# How do I reverse the smooth-step equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, algebraic-curves

I'm using the "smooth step" equation for an easing curve:

$y = 3x^2 - 2x^3$

I would like to reverse this equation so that given `y`, I can find `x`

How do I solve this?
Would something like a quadratic equation work?
Is there some sort of "cubic equation" for this?

Comment: You mean, given $y$, you find $x$?

Comment: Right. Sorry ;)

Comment: The first answer given [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3D3x%5E2-2x%5E3+for+x) works for $y<0$ or $y>1$. For $0\le y\le 1$ there is more than one answer. Which value of $x$ do you want then?

Comment: $0 <= y <= 1$
answer should be positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you cannot always do that,in this case you can;t. as it is not well defined. Assume that you can do that, and you can write $x=f(y)$. For $y=0$, correspond the values $x=0$ and $x=\frac{3}{2}$, so it's not well defined!

Comment: Hmm.. I think I see what you mean... I hope you're wrong though, so I'll leave this here till tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

If
$y = 3x^2 - 2x^3
$,
there are three main cases:
$x$ near $0$;
$x$ near $1$;
other $x$.

For $x$ near $0$,
$x^3$ is small
compared to $x^2$,
so
$y 
\approx 3x^2
$,
so
$x
\approx \sqrt{y/3}
$.

For $x$ near $1$,
let $x = 1-z$
where $z$ is small.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
y
&=3(1-z)^2 - 2(1-z)^3\\
&=3(1-2z+z^2)-2(1-3z+3z^2-z^3)\\
&=3-6z+3z^2-2+6z-6z^2+2z^3\\
&=1-3z^2+2z^3\\
\end{array}
$

so
$1-y
=3z^2-2z^3
$.
By a non-coincidence,
this eases into $1$
the same way as
it leaves $0$.
Therefore
$1-y
\approx 3z^2
$,
so
$z
\approx \sqrt{(1-y)/3}
$
or
$x
=1-z
\approx 1-\sqrt{(1-y)/3}
$.

In the middle,
let's look around
$x = 1/2$.
Let
$w = x-1/2$,
so
$x = w+1/2$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
y
&= 3(w+1/2)^2-2(w+1/2)^3\\
&= 3(w^2+w+1/4)-2(w^3+3w^2/2+3w/4+1/8)\\
&= 3w^2+3w+3/4-2w^3-3w^2-3w/2-1/4\\
&= 1/2+3w/2-2w^3\\
\end{array}
$

or
$y-1/2
=3w/2-2w^3
$.
For small $w$,
$y-1/2
\approx 3w/2
$
so
$x-1/2
=w
\approx 2(y-1/2)/3
$.
Note that this 
is linear,
not quadratic
as  for the
endpoint approximations.
This is to be expected.

For any of these,
once you have an initial approximation,
you can use Newtons iteration
of
$x
=x-(y(x)-y)/y'(x)
=x-(3x^2-2x^3-y)/(6x-6x^2)
$
to improve $x$.
You can put in
the approximate values above
for the three cases
to get a symbolic
expression
for the first iteration.
You can do some
numerical experimentation
to decide when
to switch from
the endpoint approximations
to the center approximation.